Git source control blinks constantly forever VSCode
I'm developing software on a pc that I don't have full admin permissions with and I believe git is trying to save or view a file that is not possible since no permissions. So my sidebar blinks constantly trying to do the same action over and over and I'm not sure how to make it stop.
Below is the git output log. And it just displays these over and over.
2024-09-17 11:51:27.488 [info] > git config --local branch.main.vscode-merge-base origin/main [2ms]
2024-09-17 11:51:27.488 [info] error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
2024-09-17 11:51:27.488 [warning] [Git][config] git config failed: Failed to execute git
2024-09-17 11:51:27.500 [info] > git config --get commit.template [4ms]
2024-09-17 11:51:27.500 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [1ms]
2024-09-17 11:51:27.503 [warning] [Git][revParse] Unable to read file: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'otherstuffhere/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'
2024-09-17 11:51:27.504 [info] > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main [1ms]
2024-09-17 11:51:27.510 [info] > git status -z -uall [4ms]
2024-09-17 11:51:27.516 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [0ms]
I haven't tried much since I couldn't find anything online that have the same issues.
